# Unable to Install @vitejs/plugin-vue inside Laravel project

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vite, laravel-vite

I created a fresh Laravel project. And to use Vue JS I tried installing this package,

```
@vitejs/plugin-vue
```

But this throws me a set of errors,

```
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @vitejs/plugin-vue@3.0.0
npm ERR! Found: vite@2.9.14
npm ERR! node_modules/vite
npm ERR!   dev vite@"^2.9.11" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer vite@"^2.9.9" from laravel-vite-plugin@0.4.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/laravel-vite-plugin
npm ERR!     dev laravel-vite-plugin@"^0.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer vite@"^3.0.0" from @vitejs/plugin-vue@3.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-vue
npm ERR!   @vitejs/plugin-vue@"^3.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: vite@3.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/vite
npm ERR!   peer vite@"^3.0.0" from @vitejs/plugin-vue@3.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-vue
npm ERR!     @vitejs/plugin-vue@"^3.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I followed these steps,

```
1.laravel new {proj_name}.



2. npm install vue@next.



3. npm install.



4. After that I created a vue file and imported into app.js (resources/js/app.js).



5. I went to the blade file and cleared all -> hit `!` for emmet snippet, created a div with id #app, and add
    @vite('resources/js/app.js').
```

**I throw an error saying install @vitejs/plugin-vue. But when I try to install that it throws me those errors.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
npm install vue@next vue-loader@next
npm i @vitejs/plugin-vue@2.3.3
composer require innocenzi/laravel-vite:0.2.*
npm i -D vite vite-plugin-laravel
```

vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import laravel from 'vite-plugin-laravel'

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue(),
        laravel({
        input: [
            'resources/css/app.css',
            'resources/js/app.js',
        ],
        refresh: true,
    })
    ]
})
```

maybe you need to change app.js

```
import {createApp} from 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js';
```

or for async component add defineAsyncComponent

```
import {createApp, defineAsyncComponent} from 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js';
```

@vite() leave blank

Comment: I just installed npm i @vitejs/plugin-vue@2.3.3 and it worked thanks

Answer (score 4):

If someone else is facing this issue add it directly to your package.json and then run npm i:

"@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.0.1"